undefined object while using useContext
This particular things seems happening when i run these codes
AuthContext.jsx:
// context is a state management tool for passing props
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

// initial state
const initialState = {
  user: null, //user details
  role: null,
  token: null,
};
// create a common context with initial state
export const authContext = createContext(initialState);

// reducer function
const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  // action types
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_START":
      // login starting
      return {
        user: null,
        role: null,
        token: null,
      };
    // login success
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        user: action.payload.user, //data will be recieved as a payload
        role: action.payload.role,
        token: action.payload.token,
      };
    // logout state
    case "LOGOUT": //data is set to null again
      return {
        user: null,
        role: null,
        token: null,
      };
    // default
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// export provider
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  //all children can access the provider
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState)
  return (
    <authContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        token: state.token,
        role: state.role,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
};


Login.jsx:
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import avatar_img from "../assets/images/patient-avatar.png";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { authContext } from "../context/AuthContext.jsx";
export default function Login() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { dispatch } = useContext(authContext);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    // login function parameters
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      const result = await res.json();
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(result.message || "Something went wrong");
      }
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
        payload: {
          user: result.data,
          token: result.token,
          role: result.role, //result is from the res.json()
        },
      });
      console.log(result,"login data");
      toast.success(result.message);
      setLoading(false);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Registration failed");
      setLoading(false);
      console.log("Error in registration", error.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <section className="p-3 lg:p-1">
      <div className="w-full max-w-[570px] mx-auto rounded-md shadow-xl p-3 md:p-10">
        <div className="flex justify-center gap-[20px] items-center">
          <img
            src={avatar_img}
            className="w-[40px] h-auto rounded-full"
            alt=""
          />
          <h2 className="text-3xl text-center font-semibold text-irisBlueColor">
            Login
          </h2>
        </div>
        {/* login form */}
        <form action="" className="py-4 md:py-0" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-5">
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
              placeholder="youremail@domain.com"
              className="placeholder:text-gray-400 w-full px-4 py-3 border-b border-solid border-teal-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-b-green-500 text-[15px] leading-7 cursor-text "
              value={formData.email} //setting the value as email
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-5">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
              placeholder="**********"
              className="placeholder:text-gray-400 w-full px-4 py-3 border-b border-solid border-teal-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-b-green-500 text-[15px] leading-7 cursor-text "
              value={formData.password} //setting the value as email
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <button className="btn mt-0" type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
            {/* link for register */}
            <p className=" text-textColor text-center">
              Don&apos;t have an account ,
              <Link
                to="/register"
                className=" text-irisBlueColor hover:text-primaryColor"
              >
                create one
              </Link>
            </p>
          </div>
          {/* google auth */}
          <button className="w-full outline-teal-500 rounded-2xl mt-5 font-semibold bg-primaryColor text-white p-3">
            continue with google
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}


Header.jsx:
import logo from "../../assets/images/logo.png";
import userImg from "../../assets/images/avatar-icon.png";
import { useEffect, useRef, useContext } from "react";
import { CgMenuMotion } from "react-icons/cg";
import { NavLink, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { authContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";

const navLinks = [
  { path: "/", display: "Home" },
  { path: "/doctors", display: "Find a Doctor" },
  { path: "/services", display: "Services" },
  { path: "/contact", display: "Contact" },
];

export default function Header() {
  const { user, role, token } = useContext(authContext);
  console.log(user); // Verify the user object here

  const headerRef = useRef(null);
  const menuRef = useRef(null);

  const handleStickyHeader = () => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
        headerRef.current.classList.add("sticky__header");
      } else {
        headerRef.current.classList.remove("sticky__header");
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleStickyHeader();
  }, []);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    menuRef.current.classList.toggle("show__menu");
  };

  return (
    <header className="header flex items-center" ref={headerRef}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <div>
            <img src={logo} alt="MEDICARE logo" />
          </div>
          <div className="navigation" ref={menuRef} onClick={toggleMenu}>
            <ul className="menu flex items-center gap-[2.7rem]">
              {navLinks.map((link, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                  <NavLink
                    to={link.path}
                    className={(navClass) =>
                      navClass.isActive
                        ? "text-primaryColor text-[16px] leading-7 font-[600]"
                        : "text-textColor text-[16px] leading-7 font-[500] hover:text-primaryColor"
                    }
                  >
                    {link.display}
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
            {token && user ? (
              <div>
                <Link to="/">
                  <figure className="w-[35px] h-[35px] rounded-full cursor-pointer">
                    <img src={userImg} alt="" className="w-full rounded-full" />
                  </figure>
                </Link>
                <h1>{user?.name}</h1>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <Link to="/login">
                <button className="bg-primaryColor py-2 px-7 items-center text-white font-[600] h-[44px] flex justify-center rounded-[50px]">
                  Login
                </button>
              </Link>
            )}
            <span className="md:hidden" onClick={toggleMenu}>
              <CgMenuMotion className="h-6 w-6 cursor-pointer" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}


main.jsx:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./context/AuthContext.jsx";
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <ToastContainer
          theme="dark"
          position="top-right"
          autoClose={300}
          closeOnClick
          pauseOnFocusLoss={false}
        />
        <App />
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


the problem is the code console logs role and token but it gives me user as undefined
here is the screen shot of it :
console output image for Header.jsx:
the role and token are accessible but the user is undefined in Header.jsx
Edits::
This is the screen shot of the console of the window after login img1

It sounds like result.data, on line 38 of Login.jsx might be null. Could you provide an example of the shape of the result that comes from the API? For example, that could be a typo that's supposed to say result.user? It's impossible to say without seeing an example of what JSON comes back from /api/v1/auth/login.

this is the output in the console[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iaIu0_OiqI5ZbgTa6F5P0SnktKsIIodl/view?usp=sharing
